# Creating a file inside 0766 directory fails

Tags: linux

Created a directory as root and changed its permissions to 0766:
`drwxrw-rw-  2 root root 4096 Aug  2 13:33 test/`

When running `touch test/test.txt` as a user, I get error: `touch: cannot touch 'test/test.txt': Permission denied`.

```
$getfacl /test
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rw-
other::rw-
```

The directory is set with write permission to all users, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For directories the bits of the access rights have a different meaning than for files:

- `x` means that files inside the directory may be accessed.
- `r` means that you can list the names of the files inside directory. If `r` is set but `x` is not set, `ls` can list the names of the files and sub-directories inside the directory; however, `ls` cannot show you more information if `x` is not set; not even if some file it is a regular file or a sub-directory.
- `w` is required to rename or to delete files or to create files or sub-directories inside the directory. However, [`w` has no effect if `x` is not set](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)!

> 0766 directory

Because `x` is not set for group and others, this is the same as a 0744 directory:

Other users may list the names of files and sub-directories inside the directory, but they cannot do more: They cannot even see if some file inside the directory is a regular file or a sub-directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an Access Control List (ACL), which permits the access to your folder.

I don't know very much about those lists, but this link should explain them https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists

You can view the ACL using the `getfacl` command

Comment: Seems it's something else... `$getfacl /test
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rw-
other::rw-
`